# Reusing logic in a route, nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a route that's doing a lot of processing to display a view, DB queries and parsing and that sort of thing.

I'd like to 're-use' the processing of that route that gets displayed in the view. Simply using a res.render of the view will not suffice.

I am having a hard time explaining exactly what I'm after - effectively I am trying to avoid duplicating code.

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
  ..lots of processing...    

    res.render('pages/campaigns/edit-campaign', {
        ...vars for handlebars...
    });
});    

router.all('/add/confirmation', function(req, res) {
    ... i have the data i need here, but not the processing ...
    res.render('pages/campaigns/edit-campaign-new', {
        ...vars...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a middleware that do that processing and optionally pass the processing results to handlers, if you want to use those in handlers.